# Making images appear slowly to make it realistic - Android

Tags: android, image, delay

I created a blackjack application and I've got everything works well but I want to make the application more realistic so that the cards will show up in some pace that would resemble a real dealer card distribution.
Any ideas how can I make it happen?

Comment: I don't know... how about.... animations? Have you read about Animators?

Answer (score 0):

look into animations but also if you are looking for that card thrown accross the table look create two randoms one for location and one for rotation say location +-20 and rotation +-30 and have your card be randomly offset from the hard coded location where is should be. this will make it look more realistic.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the cards to move as if they were thrown by the dealer, I suggest you use `ValueAnimator`. Then you can animate a translation value and use that value in your `onDraw` method. You would also use a `DecelerateInterpolator` to simulate the friction on the table.

```
final ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialPosition, destination);
    va.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    va.setDuration(duration);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator anim) {
            int value = (int) anim.getAnimatedValue();
            setCardTranslation(value);
            // so onDraw is called
            invalidate();
        }
    });
    va.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Animations can do a trick for you.Follow these steps for a simple animation

1. Create a folder under res name anim
2. Create a file name right_out in anim folder
3. Add the following code in that xml file

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <translate
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
   android:toXDelta="0"
   android:fromXDelta="-100%p" />

   </set>
   ```
4. In your class write this piece of code on required space.

   ```
   Animation animationFadeIn;
   animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_out);
   imageView1.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
   ```

That is all.You can find the up suggested animation in this app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tenmb.asl.americansignlanguage